# How to split a multi-line string using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I have been banging my beginner head for most of the day trying various things.

Here is the string

```
1    default                          active    Eth2/45, Eth2/46, Eth2/47
                                                Eth3/41, Eth3/42, Eth3/43
                                                Eth4/41, Eth4/42, Eth4/43
47   Production                          active    Po1, Po21, Po23, Po25, Po101
                                                Po102, Eth2/1, Eth2/2, Eth2/3
                                                Eth2/4, Eth3/29, Eth3/30
                                                Eth3/31, Eth3/32, Eth3/33
                                                Eth3/34, Eth3/35, Eth3/36
                                                Eth3/37, Eth3/38, Eth3/39
                                                Eth3/40, Eth3/44, Eth4/29
                                                Eth4/30, Eth4/31, Eth4/32
                                                Eth4/33, Eth4/34, Eth4/35
                                                Eth4/36, Eth4/37, Eth4/38
                                                Eth4/39, Eth4/40, Eth4/44
128  Test               active    Po1, Eth1/13, Eth2/1, Eth2/2
                                                Eth2/3, Eth2/4
129  Backup             active    Po1, Eth1/14, Eth2/1, Eth2/2
                                                Eth2/3, Eth2/4
```

What I need is to split like below. I have tried to use [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) to simulate various regex but I did not have much luck. I managed to isolate the delimiters with `(\n\d+)` and then I wanted to use lookbehind but I got an error saying that I need fixed string length. 
Here is a link to the regex101 [section](https://regex101.com/r/8DbPoU/1):

```
1    default                          active    Eth2/45, Eth2/46, Eth2/47
                                                Eth3/41, Eth3/42, Eth3/43
                                                Eth4/41, Eth4/42, Eth4/43
```

---

```
47   VLAN047                          active    Po1, Po21, Po23, Po25, Po101
                                                Po102, Eth2/1, Eth2/2, Eth2/3
                                                Eth2/4, Eth3/29, Eth3/30
                                                Eth3/31, Eth3/32, Eth3/33
                                                Eth3/34, Eth3/35, Eth3/36
                                                Eth3/37, Eth3/38, Eth3/39
                                                Eth3/40, Eth3/44, Eth4/29
                                                Eth4/30, Eth4/31, Eth4/32
                                                Eth4/33, Eth4/34, Eth4/35
                                                Eth4/36, Eth4/37, Eth4/38
                                                Eth4/39, Eth4/40, Eth4/44
```

---

```
128  Rogers-Refresh-MGT               active    Po1, Eth1/13, Eth2/1, Eth2/2
                                                Eth2/3, Eth2/4
```

---

```
129  ManagementSegtNorthW             active    Po1, Eth1/14, Eth2/1, Eth2/2
                                                Eth2/3, Eth2/4
```

Update: I update [the regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/8DbPoU/2) but it is not selecting what I want. The python code works. I wonder what is the problem with regex101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty simple - use lookahead instead of lookbehind:

```
parsed = re.split(r'\n(?=\d)', data)
```

Comment: This is a Pythonic way to do it ! Thank you!

Comment: regex101 shows matches, not splits - but it does show you where the string would split if you were to execute `re.split()`.

Comment: Yes this is what I expected but it did not select the vlan values (the numbers at the beginning of each line)

Comment: @MiniMe - and it shouldn't, the whole point of this pattern is to select the new line **before** the digit so we can split on it - if it were selecting the number as well, it would be missing the first digit when we split. Try setting `;` or `\n---\n` for substitution to see it in effect - that's where the cut will happen when you call `re.split()`.

Comment: Thanks, Now I got the idea :-)

Answer (score 2):

In python there is always more than one way to skin a cat. Multiline regexes are usually very hard. The following is a lot simpler, and more importantly readable

```
for line in data.split("\n"):
    if line[0].isdigit():
        if section:
            sections.append("\n".join(section))
            section=[]
        section.append(line)

sections.append("\n".join(section))  # grab the last one

print(sections)
```

Performance wise, I think this would probably be better, because we are not looking for a pattern in the entire string. we are only looking at the first character in a line.

Comment: You're missing the whole `else` case when the first character is not a digit, but even with that fix regex will still perform faster in CPython (not by much, tho) - and not because of the acquiring procedure, but because once compiled everything executes on the `C` side. On my system, `regex` performs about ~15% faster than your procedural approach (after the fix) in Python 2.7, and only a few percents on Python 3.5.

Comment: interesting @zwer i thought this would be faster. Seems you are right. Good answer from you +1